# GWT web workers unflattenKeylistIntoAnswers not defined

Tags: javascript, gwt, web-worker

I have a problem running my web workers in GWT in case i build them for more than one agent.
I receive an error that unflattenKeylistIntoAnswers function is not defined.
And indeed, the function is defined for the main JS but for the Web worker JS.
Also, some other functions such as computePropValue are not defined.

Am i missing something? Maybe some kind of a flag?

This is my gwt xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Could not determine the version of your GWT SDK; using the module DTD from GWT 1.6.4. You may want to change this. -->
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 1.6.4//EN" "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.6.4/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
<module rename-to="BucketsSnapperWorker">

    <inherits name="path.to.Core" />

    <source path="" />

    <!-- Use the WebWorker linker for a Dedicated worker-->
    <add-linker name="dedicatedworker" />

    <entry-point class="path.to.EntryPoint"/>

    <set-property name="user.agent" value="safari,gecko1_8"/>
</module>
```

Comment: I found the same problem compiling my webworkers with GWT 2.5, but with GWT 2.4 works. You also need to compile all the referenced projects with GWT 2.4, so it's better to change the default SDK globally in Window->Preferences->Google->Web Toolkit

Answer (score 1):

Since GWT 2.5 you need to force the GWT compiler to generate only one permutation for workers. Add this to your gwt xml file (replacing your user.agent property):

```
<set-property name="user.agent" value="safari"/>
<set-configuration-property name="user.agent.runtimeWarning" value="false" />
```

In my case the worker also runs in Firefox with the "safari" user.agent option.